# Passing parameters from Command to Converter

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I defined a new type of model element as a plug-in; let's refer to it as `Foo`. A `Foo` node in the model should translate to a `section` element in the view. So far, so good. I managed to do that by defining simple conversion rules. I also managed to define a new `FooCommand` that transforms (renames) selected blocks to `Foo`.

I got stuck trying to have attributes on those `Foo` model nodes be translated to attributes on the view elements (and vice-versa). Suppose Foos have an attribute named `fooClass` which should map to the view element's `class` attribute.

```
<Foo fooClass="green-foo"> should map to/from <section class="green-foo">
```

I can successfully receive parameters in `FooCommand`, but I can't seem to set them on the blocks being processed by the command:

```
execute(options = {}) {
    const document = this.editor.document;
    const fooClass = options.fooClass;

    document.enqueueChanges(() => {
        const batch = options.batch || document.batch();
        const blocks = (options.selection || document.selection).getSelectedBlocks();

        for (const block of blocks) {
            if (!block.is('foo')) {
                batch.rename(block, 'foo');
                batch.setAttribute(block, 'fooClass', fooClass);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Below is the code for the `init` function in the `Foo` plugin, including the model→view and view→model conversions:

```
init() {
    const editor = this.editor;
    const doc = editor.document;
    const data = editor.data;
    const editing = editor.editing;

    editor.commands.add('foo', new FooCommand(editor));
    doc.schema.registerItem('foo', '$block');

    buildModelConverter().for(data.modelToView, editing.modelToView)
        .fromElement('foo')
        .toElement(modelElement => {
            const fooClass = modelElement.item.getAttribute('fooClass'));
            return new ContainerElement('section', {'class': fooClass});
        });

    buildViewConverter().for(data.viewToModel)
        .fromElement('section')
        .toElement(viewElement => {
            let classes = Array.from(viewElement.getClassNames());
            let modelElement = new ModelElement('foo', {'fooClass': classes[0]});
            return modelElement;
        });

}
```

When I try to run the command via

```
editor.execute('foo', { fooClass: 'green-foo' })
```

I can see that the `green-foo` value is available to `FooCommand`, but the `modelElement` in the model→view conversion, on the other hand, has no `fooClass` attribute.

I'm sure I'm missing the point here and misusing the APIs. I'd be really thankful if someone could shed some light on this issue. I can provide more details, as needed.

### Follow-up after initial suggestions

Thanks to @Reinmar and @jodator for their suggestion regarding configuring the document schema to allow for the custom attribute. I really thought that would have taken care of it, but no. It may have been a necessary step anyway, but I'm still unable to get the attribute value from the model element during the model→view conversion.

First, let me add an important piece of information I had left out: the CKEditor5's version I'm working with is *1.0.0-alpha2*. I am aware several of the APIs are bound to change, but I would still like to get things working with the present version.

#### Model→view conversion

If I understand it correctly, one can either pass a `string` or a `function` to the `toElement` call. A question about using the latter: what exactly are the parameters passed to the function? I assumed it would be the model element (node?) to be converted. Is that the case? If so, why is the attribute set on that node via `batch.setAttribute` (inside a `document.enqueueChanges`) not available when requested? Should it be?

#### A sequencing problem?

Additional testing seems to indicate there's some kind of *order-of-execution* issue happening. I've observed that, even though the attribute is not available when I first try to read it from the `modelElement` parameter, it will be so if I read it again later. Let me try to illustrate the situation below. First, I'll modify the conversion code to make it use some dummy value in case the attribute value is not available when read:

```
buildModelConverter().for(data.modelToView, editing.modelToView)
    .fromElement('foo')
    .toElement(modelElement => {
        let fooClass = modelElement.item.getAttribute('fooClass') || 'naught';
        let viewElement = new ContainerElement('section');
        viewElement.setAttribute('class', fooClass);
        return viewElement;
    });
```

Now I reload the page and execute the following instructions on the console:

```
c = Array.from(editor.document.getRoot().getChildren());

c[1].is('paragraph'); // true

// Changing the node from 'paragraph' to 'foo' and adding an attribute
// 'fooClass' with value 'green-foo' to it.
editor.document.enqueueChanges(() => {
    const batch = editor.document.batch();
    batch.rename(c[1], 'foo');
    batch.setAttribute(c[1], 'fooClass', 'green-foo');
    return batch;
});

c[1].is('paragraph'); // false
c[1].is('foo'); // true

c[1].hasAttribute('fooClass'); // true
c[1].getAttribute('fooClass'); // 'green-foo'
```

Even though it looks like the expected output is being produced, a glance at the generated view element shows the problem:

```
<section class="naught"/>
```

Lastly, even if I try to reset the `fooClass` attribute on the model element, the change is not reflected on the view element. Why is that? Shouldn't changes made via `enqueueChanges` cause the view to update?

Sorry for the very long post, but I'm trying to convey as many details as I can. Here's hoping someone will spot my mistake or misunderstanding of how the CKEditor 5's API actually works.

### View not updating?

I turned to [`Document`'s events](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#Events) and experimented with the `changesDone` event. It successfully addresses the "timing" issue, as it consistently triggers only after all changes have been processed. Still, the problem of the view not updating in response to a change in the model remains. To make it clear, the model does change, but the view does not reflect that. Here is the call:

```
editor.document.enqueueChanges(() => editor.document.batch().setAttribute(c[1], 'fooClass', 'red-foo'));
```

Comment: A quick note as I don't know alpha-1 code that much. You've might missing an allowed attribute on model. Probably something like `editor.document.schema.allow( 'Foo', 'fooClass' );`.

Comment: Long question deserves a long answer :) So I wrote a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be 100% sure I wrote the whole feature myself. I use the 1.0.0-beta.1 API which is completely different than what you had.

Basically – it works. It isn't 100% correct yet, but I'll get to that.

### How to convert an element+attribute pair?

The thing when implementing a feature which needs to convert element + attribute is that it requires handling the element and attribute conversion separately as they are treated separately by CKEditor 5.

Therefore, in the code below you'll find that I used [`elementToElement()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html#function-elementToElement):

```
editor.conversion.elementToElement( {
    model: 'foo',
    view: 'section'
} );
```

So a converter between model's `<foo>` element and view's `<section>` element. This is a two-way converter so it handles upcasting (view -> model) and downcasting (model -> view) conversion.

NOTE: It doesn't handle the attribute.

Theoretically, as the `view` property you could write a callback which would read the model element's attribute and create view element with this attribute set too. But that wouldn't work because such a configuration would only make sense in case of downcasting (model -> view). How could we use that callback to downcast a view structure?

NOTE: You can write converters for downcast and upcast pipelines separately (by using [`editor.conversion.for()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html#function-for)), in which case you could really use callbacks. But it doesn't really make sense in this case.

### The attribute may change independently!

The other problem is that let's say you wrote an element converter which sets the attribute at the same time. Tada, you load `<section class=ohmy>` and gets `<foo class=ohmy`> in your model.

But then... what if the attribute will change in the model?

In the downcast pipeline CKEditor 5 treats element changes separately from attribute changes. It fires them as separate events. So, when your `FooCommand` is executed on a heading it calls `writer.rename()` and we get the following events in [`DowncastDispatcher`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcastdispatcher-DowncastDispatcher.html):

1. `remove` with `<heading>`
2. `insert:section`

But then the attribute is changed too (`writer.setAttribute()`), so we also get:

3. `setAttibute:class:section`

The `elementToElement()` conversion helper listens to `insert:section` event. So it's blind to `setAttribute:class:selection`.

Therefore, when you change the value of the attribute, you need the `attributeToAttribute()` conversion.

### Sequencing

I didn't want to reply to your question before we released 1.0.0-beta.1 because 1.0.0-beta.1 brought the [Differ](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_differ-Differ.html).

Before 1.0.0-beta.1 all changes were converted immediately when they were applied. So, `rename()` would cause immediate `remove` and `insert:section` events. At this point, the element that you got in the latter one wouldn't have the `class` attribute set yet.

Thanks to the Differ we're able to start the conversion once all the changes are applied (after `change()` block is executed). This means that the `insert:section` event is fired once the model `<foo>` element has the `class` attribute set already. That's why you could write a callback-based converters... bur you shouldn't :D

### The code

```
import { downcastAttributeToAttribute } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/downcast-converters';
import { upcastAttributeToAttribute } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/conversion/upcast-converters';

class FooCommand extends Command {
    execute( options = {} ) {
        const model = this.editor.model;
        const fooClass = options.class;

        model.change( writer => {
            const blocks = model.document.selection.getSelectedBlocks();

            for ( const block of blocks ) {
                if ( !block.is( 'foo' ) ) {
                    writer.rename( block, 'foo' );
                    writer.setAttribute( 'class', fooClass, block );
                }
            }
        } );
    }
}

class FooPlugin extends Plugin {
    init() {
        const editor = this.editor;

        editor.commands.add( 'foo', new FooCommand( editor ) );

        editor.model.schema.register( 'foo', {
            allowAttributes: 'class',
            inheritAllFrom: '$block'
        } );

        editor.conversion.elementToElement( {
            model: 'foo',
            view: 'section'
        } );

        editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).add(
            upcastAttributeToAttribute( {
                model: 'class',
                view: 'class'
            } )
        );

        editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' ).add(
            downcastAttributeToAttribute( {
                model: 'class',
                view: 'class'
            } )
        );

        // This should work but it does not due to https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/issues/1379 :(((    
        // EDIT: The above issue is fixed and will be released in 1.0.0-beta.2.
        // editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute( {
        //  model: {
        //      name: 'foo',
        //      key: 'class'
        //  },
        //  view: {
        //      name: 'section',
        //      key: 'class'
        //  }
        // } );
    }
}
```

This code works quite well, except the fact that it converts the `class` attribute on any possible element that has it. That's because I had to use very generic `downcastAttributeToAttribute()` and `upcastAttributeToAttribute()` converters because of a [bug that I found](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/issues/1379) (*EDIT: it's fixed and will be available in 1.0.0-beta.2*). The commented out piece of code is how you it should be defined if everything worked fine and it will work in 1.0.0-beta.2.

It's sad that we missed such a simple case, but that's mainly due to the fact that all our features... are much more complicated than this.

Comment: Thank you very, very much for taking the time to respond, @Reinmar. I can only imagine how much you guys have on your plates as CK Editor 5 approaches an initial 1.0 release. There's a lot of interesting bits of information in your answer. Thank you!